# Moving Data into destination sheet and formatting output

Tags: excel, vba

I have my data in columns A:L in Sheet2 and wish to copy each block based on the starting point, as certain cell text and the end point, again as certain cell text! The data is in columns A:L and move down down block by block
[image]

The code I have is very nearly 100% complete, but the last part I am trying to achieve is to put each item in a specific order on the destination sheet. As we know columns are A:L I want to paste my first block into Columns A:L in the destination then the next one in M:X then the final one in Y:AJ.
As there are about 10 of these blocks, Tank Engine, Weatherman etc I envisage, that I will need three blocks first, then a about three rows which are gaps before it is then repeated.

An example of this

[image]

The rows are dynamic but never more than 11 in length. The code I have is

```
Option Explicit

Sub MIKE3()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet 'define source
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet 'define destination
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim FindList As Variant 'defind search words
    FindList = Array("Tank Engine")

    Dim i As Long

    Dim FindItm As Variant
    For Each FindItm In FindList
        Dim CopyRange As Range
        Set CopyRange = FindMyRange(wsSrc.Range("A:L"), FindItm, "INFORMATION: " & FindItm)
        If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            CopyRange.Copy wsDest.Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=i) 'note that if the first column uses merged cells the ColumnOffset:=i otherwise it is ColumnOffset:=i*12
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next FindItm
End Sub
Function FindMyRange(SearchInRange As Range, ByVal StartString As String, ByVal EndString As String) As Range
   'find start
    Dim FoundStart As Range
    Set FoundStart = SearchInRange.Find(What:=StartString, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If FoundStart Is Nothing Then GoTo ERR_NOTHING_FOUND
    find end
    Dim FoundEnd As Range
    Set FoundEnd = SearchInRange.Find(What:=EndString, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=FoundStart)

    If FoundEnd Is Nothing Then GoTo ERR_NOTHING_FOUND

    Set FindMyRange = SearchInRange.Parent.Range(FoundStart, FoundEnd).Resize(ColumnSize:=12)

    Exit Function'

ERR_NOTHING_FOUND:
    FindMyRange = Nothing
End Function
```

thanks to PEH for his initial help and Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work by editing the strings in my source data then writing x number of macros to cover my scenarios then calling them one by one in a module